# Error Inventor!

Tags: error

In reference to the patent: [WO2017179083A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2017179083A1)

L'inventore si chiama Giuseppe Verde. Si prega di correggere.
(The inventor is called Giuseppe Verde. Please correct.)

Comment: Error Surname: "Verdi"

Surname is: "Verde"

Comment: Can you please translate your question into English? I gather you are asking about the fact that the patent application has misspelled your last name. If so, I assume asking your patent attorney to request the patent authorities to make the correction would be a reasonable step.

Comment: the surname has been corrected on the WIPO website. But on google patents it has not been corrected yet.

Comment: Nor is it correct on The Lens. I have no idea how to get third party sites to fix this. Posting here won’t work. Great name, by the way!

Comment: Not an exact duplicate in that the error isn't due to OCR and is found on other patent searching sites.

Comment: On "lens patent" has been corrected. Now it remains google patents, which is on the "Send Feedback" button, I do not receive an answer.